# Should I delete a wrong question?

Tags: discussion, deleted-questions, rules

I asked a question (and even got some answers) but then I realized that I'm an idiot, **I have a typo in my source code** and *that's* the reason it does not work, the question is irrelevant. (One of the answers actually suggests the typo).

Now should I delete the question? It clearly has no value for others.

The reason I'm asking is b/c deleting a question with existing answers seems to be against the rules and "can result in your account being blocked from asking" (quoting the popped up message-box).

PS. the question [Wildcard to match files with two "dots"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43117548/wildcard-to-match-files-with-two-dots/43118231)

Comment: You can't delete your own question when it has (an) upvoted answer(s)

Comment: @rene Seems like I can. Probably because of my reputation points...

Comment: @jazzcat If you click the `delete` link it will simply tell you that you can't delete it.  You need 10k rep to vote to delete a question, but to be able to vote to delete it even then it has to have been closed for over 5 days for you to be eligible to vote.

Comment: @jazzcat No you can't, not with 2k+ rep (and not even with higher rep).

Comment: @Servy to cast a delete vote on own question, even 1 reputation is enough.

Comment: @ShadowWizard If the post is eligible for unilateral deletion by the author, yes.  This post isn't.

Comment: I agree with @rene you can't delete when your question have an upvoted answer. First it will prompt the message you said in question and when you click on delete, it simply say you can't delete. I suggest Flag it for Mod and say what is the issue and why you want to delete the question